# Do we need ufw in gcp? or gcp's firewall is good enough?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, hosting, ufw

Do we need ufw in gcp? or gcp's provided Firewall is good enough?

Comment: What's your concern? What feature is missing in GCP firewalls?

Comment: GCP VPC Firewall is sufficient.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No my concern was : is gcp firewall sufficient for protecting my Instance or I need to use ufw as I have seen in some tutorials of DigitalOcean where ufw is used for DigitalOcean Droplets.

Comment: @Kolban Thanks a Lot. That Clears my Confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve you have a choice to use firewall at VM Instance level or GCP level.

**Google Cloud Platform blocks some traffic for security reasons** - such as GRE, SMTP (egress traffic to port 25) and some other less popular protocols. **You can find more information on [always blocked traffic in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic).**

Furthermore - by default if you create a VPC network ports 22 & 3389 are blocked. You have to allow traffic in/out when creating instance or create a proper [firewall rule](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list)  later. This is also done for security.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.I have completely got it and would be continuing gcp firewall without any doubt.Thanks once again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If you think my answer is useful to you I'd appreciate if you accpted it :)